# Two foreign keys and a value in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am a newbie to django, so the question might be dumb, but please feel free to teach me the right way if you know it.
I tried googling the issue, but I am still at loss.
Here's my problem:

I have a class in my model that has two foreign keys:

```
class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name

class Y(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name

class Z(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    x = models.ForeignKey(X)
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return name
```

In my view I get a partial list of X objects and a partial list of Y objects like so:

```
def MyView(x_pattern, y_pattern):
    x_list = X.objects.filter(name__contains=x_pattern)
    y_list = Y.objects.filter(name__contains=y_pattern)
    z_list = Z.objects.all()
    return render_to_response({'x_list': x_list, 'y_list': y_list, 'z_list': z_list})
```

In my template I'd like to be able to display a table like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Y</td>
   {% for x in x_list %}
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
   {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for y in y_list %}
   <tr>
    <td>{{ y }}</td>
    {% for x in x_list %}
     <td>
      <!-- here I need help: 
           I need to display z[x, y] if it exists, or "N/A" otherwise.
      -->
     </td>
    {% endfor %}
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

How do I do this properly in django?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

As @DZPM [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750783/two-foreign-keys-and-a-value-in-django-template/3751039#3751039), you should think of keeping the logic in your view. [sheepish] I once invented my own "Table" data structure to do something very similar. The table was had rows corresponding to `X`, columns corresponding to `Y` and cells corresponding to `Z[X, Y]`. I then wrote `get_row` and `get_cell` filters to do the trick in the template. [/sheepish]

That said, what you want can be accomplished using a pair of custom filters. This solution is rather verbose.

```
@register.filter
def x_is(value, x):
    return value.x == x

@register.filter
def y_is(value, y):
    return value.y == y
```

You can use these filters in the template as shown below:

```
{% if z|x_is:x and z|y_is:y %}
    {{ z }}
{% else %}
    N/A
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much - that was the missing link (custom filters).

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the logic in your view. Why don't you just filter the z_list there?

```
z_list = Z.objects.filter(x__name__contains=x_pattern, y__name__contains=y_pattern)
```

Comment: I can filter the list in the view, yet it still does not help me display it properly (i.e. I need to map (x,y) key pair to z[x,y] value in the template in order to display it in a proper table cell). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a generator in your view, and then send it to your template context:

```
# nested inside your view function
def x_and_z_list(y):
    for x in x_list:
        z_obj = x.z_set.filter(y=y)
        z_name = z_obj or 'N/A'
        yield {'x': x, 'z': z_name}
return render_to_response('mytemplate', {'list_generator': x_and_z_list}
```

Then your template could look like this:

```
{% for y in y_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ y }}</td>
        {% for pair in list_generator.y %}  {# pair is the dict you yielded before #}
            <td>{{ pair.x.name }}: {{ pair.z }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the concepts of custom filter and functions as first class objects making a template filter into a functor (function-object).

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
def z_filter(x, y):
    z_list = list(Z.objects.filter(x, y))
    return z_list.pop().name or 'N/A'
register.filter(z_filter)
```

In template:

```
{% load z_filter %}
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Y</td>
  {% for x in x_list %}
   <td>{{ x }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
 </tr>
 {% for y in y_list %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{ y }}</td>
    {% for x in x_list %}
     <td>{{ x|z_filter:y }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks everybody for your help!